# Complex Regex not working in Spacy entity ruler

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to identify the entities by passing the Regular expression (Regex) to the Spacy model using Entity Ruler but, Spacy is unable to identify based on the below regex.

But, I tested the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/A5iiWc/4) and it's working.

```
import model_training
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
nlp.add_pipe("spacytextblob")

nlp = model_training.train_model_with_regex(nlp)
```

model_training.py

```
def train_model_with_regex(nlp):
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
patterns = [
    {
        "label": "VOLUME",
        "pattern": [{"LOWER": {'REGEX': "(?:\d+\s(?:million|hundred|thousand|billion)*\s*)+"}}]
    }
]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
return nlp
```

I wanted to achieve this, for the below example

```
text = "I have spent 5 million to buy house and 70 thousand for the furniture"
```

expected output:

```
{'result': [
    {'label': 'VOLUME', 'text': '5 million'},
    {'label': 'VOLUME', 'text': '70 thousand'}
]}
```

Comment: You are trying to match several tokens with a single regex, but `REGEX` is applied to each token separately.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the response, I just tried with this `{"label": "VOLUME", "pattern": [{"LOWER": {'REGEX': r"(?:\d+\s(?:million)*\s*)+"}}]}` but still didn't work

Comment: Backslashes in strings need to be doubled, or you need to use a raw string `r"..."` for the regex.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I tried but didn't work

Comment: I know you tried it, and it is wrong. You must provide  a pattern with `REGEX`s for several tokens.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, I'm getting your point. To identify multiple tokens, I need multiple `REGEX`. But in my case, how can I identify `any_number million` (ex: 5 million) as custom entity (as `VOLUME`) ? (I have also edited my question), thanks.

Comment: I think it should be something like `"pattern": [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*$"}}, {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^(?:million|hundred|thousand|billion)s?$"}}]`. Or use `'LIKE_NUM': True` instead of `"REGEX": r"^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*$"`

Comment: Thanks very much @WiktorStribiżew, both the `REGEX`s working, In my case, `LIKE_NUM` will be very helpful. But I'm getting a warning `[W035] Discarding subpattern '{'LIKE_NUM': True}' due to an unrecognized attribute or operator. self.matcher.add(label, [pattern])` any idea? can I ignore?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm happy to accept your answer if you post, thank again.

Comment: Looks like `LIKE_NUM` is specific for each language, and is probably unavailable when training (or you need to write a custom method). I suggest a regex for any number that can contain dots or commas in between the digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern is supposed to match at least two tokens, while the `REGEX` operator is applied to a single token.

A solution can look like

```
"pattern": [
    {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*$"}},
    {"TEXT": {"REGEX": r"^(?:million|hundred|thousand|billion)s?$"}}
]
```

The `LIKE_NUM` entity is defined  in Spacy source code mostly as a string of digits with all dots and commas removed, so the `^\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*$` pattern looks good enough. It matches a token that starts with one or more digits and then contains zero or more occurrences of a comma or dot and then one or more digits till the end of the token.